# Fastest way to remove rows that contain substrings of values in the same column of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, substring

I am trying to write some efficient code that removes rows of a pandas dataframe with values in a specific column that are substrings of other values (subset of at least one value) in the same column.
For example, consider column `B` in the following input Dataframe:

```
|   | A  | B          |
|---|----|------------|
| 0 | 22 | ab         |
| 1 | 33 | abc        |
| 2 | 44 | abcd       |
| 3 | 55 | a          |
| 4 | 66 | john       |
| 5 | 77 | john Doe   |
| 6 | 88 | jo         |
| 7 | 99 | john hi Doe|
```

Output Dataframe:

```
|   | A  | B          |
|---|----|------------|
| 2 | 44 | abcd       |
| 5 | 77 | john Doe   |
| 7 | 99 | john hi Doe|
```

Rows 0, 1, and 3 have been removed because all of their values for column `B` (`ab`, `abc`, and `a`) are substrings of other values in that column (i.e. `abcd`). This is also the case for rows 4 and 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use some list comprehesnion to check if row strings are in other rows of the dataframe:

```
m = df['B'].apply(lambda x: any([x for y in df['B'] if x != y if x in y]))
df = df[~m]
df
Out[1]: 
    A            B
2  44         abcd
5  77     john Doe
7  99  john hi Doe
```

Comment: Thanks David. Your code works correctly. If no more efficient answer is provided, I will mark your answer. I wonder if there is a faster way to get the same result?